# `brew edit` not using EDITOR

Tags: homebrew

When I do `brew edit SOMEFORMULA`, it opens the formula in nano despite the fact that my $EDITOR variable is set to "mvim". Other applications respect and use $EDITOR. Homebrew is supposed to-- any idea what's going on?

Comment: Is your $VISUAL set to nano?

Comment: @echristopherson Why yes it is. I didn't even know that variable existed. I changed it and the problem is now solved... you should create a solution so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many command-line utilities look at both the variables `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL`. It appears `brew` prioritizes `$VISUAL`; if it's set, it will use its value as the editor command.

I'm not sure if all or most utilities similarly prioritize `$VISUAL`, or indeed how many of them notice it at all. Apparently your other programs don't pay attention to it, or privilege `$EDITOR` over it.